# Real time cmd tool to show HDD space remaining

Tags: debian, ubuntu, terminal, hard-disk, real-time

Is there a command line tool which shows in real time how much space remains on my external hard drive?

Comment: The answer depends on the file system. For example `df` can not show the correct values for btrfs (yet). Could you add this information to your question?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As Julie said, you can use `df` to display free space, passing it either the mount point or the device name:

```
df --human-readable /home
df --human-readable /dev/sda1
```

You'll get something like this:

```
Filesystem Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1  833G  84G  749G  10%  /home
```

To run it continuously, use `watch`. Default update interval is 2 seconds, but you can tweak that with `--interval`:

```
watch --interval=60 df --human-readable /dev/sda1
```

Answer (score 3):

`df` is a simple command line utility that shows you disk usage, including free space.

Check `man df` for details.

Comment: I currently use `df -h`, which gives me the required info as and when I type `df -h`.  I was after something more live or real time, i.e. something which keeps updating the terminal automatically, so I don't have to type in a command to check.

Comment: @oshirowanen You can use `watch`, and it will run it over and over and show you fresh output (normally every two seconds). Keep in mind that only one program can update the terminal at a time under normal conditions (i.e. if you don't want to make a complete mess of your screen), so if you want to do other things at the same time you need to dedicate a terminal to it or run it in something like screen, tmux, or dvtm to split the terminal into multiple virtual terminals.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like the idea of dedicating a whole terminal to `watch`ing the output of `df`, you could consider a tool such as [conky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conky_%28software%29). There are countless examples of using `conky` to monitor everything from HDD usage, HDD temp, ram usage, local weather, news headlines... you name it.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the following:

```
watch -d df
```

Comment: You should [edit] this answer to include an explanation of how this  differs from the accepted answer - which already provides explanations on how to use the `df` and `watch` commands.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [excellent answer provided above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280625/332288) by [Alexander Batischev](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/167612/alexander-batischev), and [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465129/332288) by [Ralf Friedl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/301065/ralffriedl), I combined them with "sort" a la [this link](https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/8111/df-output-sorted-by-use-and-correctly-maintaining-header-row) for this command:

```
watch -d -n 60 'df -H /dev/sd[a-z][0-9] | sort -r -k 5 -i'
```

That will let you watch all of your hard drives in a terminal, updated every minute, sorted by percentage of space used.

I don't know how much this answer may add to what is already here (this is my very first answer), but I thought I would put it here, in case someone comes looking for exactly what I wanted to do, which is how I ended up on this question in the first place.  Thought I would try to save someone else the effort of having to figure out how to put "watch", "df" and "sort" together, if I could.

FYI, I used regex instead of just "/dev/sd*" because my system also shows several "udev" entries, which I didn't need or want to see.  The command as written above hides those and only shows hard drives.