# `watch` command with piping `|`

Tags: linux, pipe, watch, slurm

I want to keep monitoring a specific job on a slurm worload like cluster. I tried to use the `watch` command and `grep` the specific `id`. If the job id is`4138`, I tried

```
$> watch squeue -u mnyber004 | grep 4138
$> squeue -u mnyber004 | watch grep 4138
```

but they doesn't work. The second command works for the first few seconds, but stop working when `watch` refreshes.

A better idea please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to quote the command

```
watch 'squeue -u mnyber004 | grep 4138'
```

Answer (score 4):

The other answer covers how to handle using the 'watch' utility with a pipe but since you're using Slurm and know the job ID, just ask Slurm for that job's status:

```
$> watch squeue -j 4138
```